# Where should the true delegate of an adapted view be implemented?

Tags: ios, delegates

I am going to try and setup my App so that it can use either an Apple map or a Google map, so I think I will have something like this:

```
class AppleMap: MKMapView, MyMapProtocol {
  var delegate: MyMapDelegateProtocol
...
}

class GoogleMap: GMSMapView, MyMapProtocol {
  var delegate: MyMapDelegateProtocol
...
}
```

Both MKMapView and GMSMapView each have delegates.  Many of the calls to these delegates will just get translated and passed to the Apple/GoogleMap delegate, but some will need to be handled uniquely (such as viewForAnnotaion)

**The question is where should the MKMapViewDelegate and GMSMapViewDelegate be implemented?**

I am thinking the AppleMap and GoogleMap classes, but I figure this is a fairly common thing to do (wrapping a class that has a delegate in an adapter class),  but I have not seen any best practices documented.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement them as independent model classes so that their code remains encapsulated from the rest of your application. Variables for these objects can live in a custom MapChildViewController object that just manages the logic between these maps for you. Allowing you to reuse this logic across your app. How does this sound?

Comment: I am not exactly sure where you were going with this answer, but this did provide me a hint as to what I think is the right way to do this.  The hint came from "ChildViewController".  I have a MapViewController, which can have one of 2 ChildViewControllers active.  A AppleMapViewController or a GoogleMapViewController.  Each of these implements the delegate for it's given view and also forwards messages to a delegate implemented by the MapViewController.  I will post the details when I can submit an answer of my own.  Thanks for the hint tho!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and glad I could help!